What is the difference between Xを同伴する and Xを同伴させる?
A military squadron was assigned a task by a supervisor:

この班への課題は十歳の少女を同伴させるというものに決まった。

It seems to me that 少女を同伴させる here means the same thing as 少女を同伴する. Is there any difference between these two?


少女を同伴する
to have/take a girl as a companion
少女を同伴させる
to make/let a girl accompany you

The former only expresses the fact that the girl is with the speaker. The latter involves causation, i.e., asking, allowing or ordering the girl to go somewhere with the speaker.
